# protractor, how to get href, multiple, values

Tags: jasmine, protractor

How can i get the href value per "a"?

```
<div class="nea-sidebar" _ngcontent-c2="">
<a class="sidebar-item active" href="#/test" _ngcontent-c2="" routerlinkactive="active" ng-reflect-router-link="test" ng-reflect-router-link-active="active">
<i class="sidebar-icon fas fa-play" _ngcontent-c2="" ng-reflect-klass="sidebar-icon fas" ng-reflect-ng-class="fa-play"></i>
<span class="sidebar-label" _ngcontent-c2="">Start Test</span></a>

<a class="sidebar-item" href="#/sequences" _ngcontent-c2="" routerlinkactive="active" ng-reflect-router-link="sequences" ng-reflect-router-link-active="active">
<i class="sidebar-icon fas fa-project-diagram" _ngcontent-c2="" ng-reflect-klass="sidebar-icon fas" ng-reflect-ng-class="fa-project-diagram"></i>
<span class="sidebar-label" _ngcontent-c2="">Sequences</span></a>
```

This is only a part of the code, I have 5 different href to get

I'm using:

```
element.all(by.css('a')).count().then(function(numberOfTRs) {
for (let i = 1; i <= numberOfTRs; i ++) {
            expect(element(by.css('a')).getAttribute('href')).toMatch('http://localhost:4200/#/sequence');
}
});
```

It Returns

```
returns:
  - Expected 'http://localhost:4200/#' to match 'http://localhost:4200/#/sequence'.
  - Expected 'http://localhost:4200/#' to match 'http://localhost:4200/#/sequence'.
  - Expected 'http://localhost:4200/#' to match 'http://localhost:4200/#/sequence'.
  - Expected 'http://localhost:4200/#' to match 'http://localhost:4200/#/sequence'.
  - Expected 'http://localhost:4200/#' to match 'http://localhost:4200/#/sequence'.
  - Expected 'http://localhost:4200/#' to match 'http://localhost:4200/#/sequence'.

Executed 1 of 1 spec (1 FAILED) in 22 secs.
```

Comment: you need to refer to i. Otherwise, element(by.css('a') will keep getting the first one over and over. But it is probably cleaner to use a .each(). Also, I think by.tagName('a') might be less likely to match stuff you don't mean (though perhaps it is equivalent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For only getting all `href` values of all `a` elements you can do the following:

```
element.all(by.tagName('a')).map((function (el) {
  return el.getAtrribute('href');   
});
```

Probably you are going to check if a set of links is present on the page. You could achieve that as follows:

```
// the urls you are expecting to be on the page
var expectedUrls = ['/home', '/sequence', '/other'];
element.all(by.tagName('a')).map((function (el) {
    return el.getAttribute('href');
})).then(function (urls) {
  urls.forEach(function (url) {
    expect(expectedUrls.some(function (expUrl) {
      return expUrl === url;
    })).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

#### Explanation:

`element.all(by.tagName('a'))` collects all a elements

`.map()` converts all elements to its `href` value.

`array.some()` checks wheter atleast one element fullfills condition

=> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

Let me know if you have any questions or provided code doesn't work out. (did not test)

Comment: "- Failed: expectedUrls is not defined" 
expectedUrl or expectedUrls isn´t recognized.

Comment: asjusted answer.

Comment: thank you, it works. 
I only need to put full urls on the array.

    const expectedUrls = [ 'http://localhost:4200/#', 'http://localhost:4200/#/test', 'http://localhost:4200/#/sequences',
          'http://localhost:4200/#/identifier', 'http://localhost:4200/#/results' , 'http://localhost:4200/#/settings' ];

Comment: Yes the contents of `expectedUrls` was just dummy content.

Answer (score 0):

I went about this a slightly different way. I like that I can easily add more validation and expects on each element within the loop; hopefully someone else finds this helpful. Any feedback is appreciated!

```
// Ideally you'd be using POM
const tempElements = element.all(by.css('a'));

// Check for '/' in url and print list of hrefs to console.
async function getElementsLinks(elements: ElementArrayFinder){
  const tempList = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < await elements.count(); i++) {
    const temp = await elements.get(i).getAttribute('href');
    expect(temp).toContain('/');
    tempList.push(temp);
  }
  console.log(tempList);
}

// Call the function on an ElementArrayFinder object
await getElementsLinks(tempElements);
```